# How to create a reverse proxy on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a web app running on **localhost:5000**

I would like to serve this app using Nginx and an external domain.

I configured Nginx as follows :

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
                    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:5000 /;
  }
}
```

After restarting Nginx, what this code does is when typing example.com on Chrome, it redirects (on the client side) to 127.0.0.1:5000 which results obviously in the error : This site can’t be reached

What I need, is not a redirection on the client side but, serving the url http://127.0.0.1:5000 on the server side and send it back to the end user.

Can anyone help please ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the proxy_redirect line. Proxy_pass should be enough.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working unfortunately. Still the same error

Comment: That's very strange. I added example.com to my local etc/hosts and just copied your code except for the proxy_redirect line. It worked totally fine. Did you remember to restart the service by sudo service nginx restart?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed that the modifications to configuration file were not taken into account. Now they do and it's working. Thanks man :) !